How to use `ScriptableRenderContext.Cull` without camera?
I'm trying to implement custom lightning system for my game. For this purpose, I want to render a shadowmap texture. I want to do this without using any camera, but only basing on light object transform. I write this code to do this:
var pos = _transform.position;

var farClipPlane = new Plane(Vector3.forward, pos + Vector3.forward * _nearClip);
var nearClipPlane = new Plane(-Vector3.forward, pos + Vector3.forward * _farClip);

var cullParams = new ScriptableCullingParameters()
{
    isOrthographic = true,
    cullingMatrix =  _projectionMatrix,
    origin = pos,
    cullingOptions = CullingOptions.None,
    cullingPlaneCount = 2,
    maximumVisibleLights = 0,
};

cullParams.SetCullingPlane(0, farClipPlane);
cullParams.SetCullingPlane(1, nearClipPlane);

var cullData = context.Cull(ref cullParams);

_commandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(_depthTexture);
_commandBuffer.ClearRenderTarget(true, true, Color.clear);
_commandBuffer.SetViewMatrix(_viewMatrix);
_commandBuffer.SetProjectionMatrix(_projectionMatrix);

var rendererListDesc = new RendererListDesc(new ShaderTagId("UniversalForward") , cullData, renderingData.cameraData.camera)
{
    sortingCriteria = SortingCriteria.CommonOpaque,
    rendererConfiguration = PerObjectData.None,
    renderQueueRange = RenderQueueRange.opaque,
    overrideMaterial = _testMaterial
};

var rendererList = context.CreateRendererList(rendererListDesc);

_commandBuffer.DrawRendererList(rendererList);

context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(_commandBuffer);
_commandBuffer.Clear();

But got an error on 19th line in var cullData = context.Cull(ref cullParams);. The error is next: A valid camera must be specified to provide for per-camera intermediate renderers & LOD fade.
How can I solve this and get a CullingResults without using Camera component?

Well according to that error you can't ... Afaik you should not create new parameters by constructor but rather use Camera.TryGetCullingParameters

@derHugo maybe you know a way to render some count of objects without DrawRendererList, but still with single drawcall? This would also solve my problem.

You could probably go through Graphics directly .. but tbh I don't really fully understand yet what you try to do
